# Kill a listening port for a specific IP

Tags: linux, networking, port, ubuntu-14.04, sip

I have a SIP server with multiple network interfaces. (virtual) When I execute the command `netstat -nlput` it shows the all listening IP and ports as below.

```
root@DUO-CALLSERVER004:/etc/init.d# netstat -nlput
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      723/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.238:8021     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1835/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1868/nrpe
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.118:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.117:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.114:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.112:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.110:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.238:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.111:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.116:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 172.20.112.115:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.168.52.108:5060     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21036/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      723/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1835/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5666                 :::*                    LISTEN      1868/nrpe
udp        0      0 172.20.112.118:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.117:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.114:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.112:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.110:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.238:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.111:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.116:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 172.20.112.115:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 192.168.52.108:5060     0.0.0.0:*                           21036/freeswitch
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           723/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:731             0.0.0.0:*                           723/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                723/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::731                  :::*                                723/rpcbind
```

what I want is to kill the port 5060 which is listening on 172.20.112.117:5060. But another set of IPs also listing the same port using the same PID. I don't want to kill those. Only the 172.20.112.117 IP need to release from the 5060 port. Is there a method to do this ?

Comment: Depends on if different processes bind to the different IP addresses, or not. Use `lsof` to find which process listens on `172.20.112.117:5060`. If it doesn't listen on other ports, kill it.

Comment: ...which, conveniently, is already shown in the netstat output's "PID/Program" column.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the process in a way that makes him bind only to the correct addresses instead of `0.0.0.0`. If the process is [Freeswitch](http://freeswitch.org) you should have a look at the configuration. From the [Mailing List](http://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2008-May/003086.html) (though dated):

> Dude,
>   Straight out of the default config:

```
<!-- bind_server_ip
   Can be an ip address, a dns name, or "auto".
   This determines an ip address available on this host to bind.
   If you are separating RTP and SIP traffic, you will want to have
   use different addresses where this variable appears.
   Used by: sofia.conf.xml dingaling.conf.xml
-->
  <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="bind_server_ip=auto"/>
```

Alternatively from the [Wiki](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Config_vars.xml).

Comment: its interesting that it put a listener on each IP. usually when binding to 0.0.0.0/all-Interfaces, the binding is on 0.0.0.0 per netstat. Must be a VOIP thing.

Comment: It's just my assumption. It might be wrong, as the config says "auto" it could be what they indent. I didn't really check into the specifics of that software.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Probably for symmetry with UDP – and in UDP that's still frequently done because older operating systems couldn't tell you which address a packet was sent to, so you couldn't correctly send the reply out. ntpd and krb5-kdc do this, at least.